# can jekyll arrays have spaces?

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

in my front matter, i have categories like below.

```
categories: ['hello world', 'code', 'lunch']
```

but when i try to break them up, it's splits them with spaces instead of the comma. i'm using the following code.

```
{% capture categories %}
{% for category in site.categories | join: ' '%}
{{ category[0] }}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign sortedcategories = categories | split:' ' | sort %}

{% for category in sortedcategories %}
<h3>{{ category }}</h3>

<ul>
{% for post in site.categories[category] %}
  <li>{{ post.url }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endfor %}
```

i tried to use a semicolon as the delimiter but when i get to the site.categories[category], that part fails and does not display anything on the list. any ideas? or should i use categories without spaces? or use hyphens?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is :

```
{% assign sortedcategories = page.categories | sort %}

{% for category in sortedcategories %}
<h3>{{ category }}</h3>

<ul>
{% for post in site.categories[category] %}
  <li>{{ post.url }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endfor %}
```

---

In your front matter, the `categories: ['hello world', 'code', 'lunch']` creates an array.
And what your doing in your first five lines is useless.

I also thing that there is a misunderstanding on what join and split are doing :

#### join

`{{ page.categories | join: "::" }}` => string `"hello world::code::lunch"`

#### split

`{{ "hello world::code::lunch" | split: "::"` => array `['hello world', 'code', 'lunch']`

Notes :

- front mater variables are reached with `page.variable`
- you cannot use a filter in a loop. eg : `{% for category in site.categories | sort %}` You must first assign to a variable, then loop through it.

Comment: well, what i'm trying to do is create a categories.html page that lists all the categories i've used. within each category, i'd like to list posts that have that category. which is why i used site.categories and not page.categories.

Comment: In your question you talk about front matter. For me that means that your array is declared in your page/post.

Answer (score 0):

okay i got the answer. line breaks are VERY important. i don't know how many times i read that yet i still forget/ignore it. here's my final code.

```
{% capture categories %}
  {% for category in site.categories %}{{ category | first }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign sortedcategories = categories | split: ',' | sort %}

{% for category in sortedcategories %}
  <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for post in site.categories[category] %}
      <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

so the first 3 lines of code creates categories and stores all site.categories values delimited by a comma. this is where i messed up - line 2 should all be one line and not broken up. otherwise the for loop that checks site.categories[category] will never match. which is why i get the list of categories but i never got the posts that belonged to each one.

Comment: Your three first lines are doing a `site.categories | join:","` then do a `split | sort`. It's useless.

A `site.categories | sort` is enough.